# Turning MIPS instruction into Binary, then into Hexadecimal

Tags: c, file, binary, hex, mips

For a class project I need to read in a file of at least for MIPS instructions like:

```
add $t0, $s1, $s4
addi $t1, $a0, 7
```

and so on...(I can make the file whatever I want and I only need to worry about I and R format)
my problem is reading from the file and actually converting it to binary first, then binary to hexadecimal should'nt be hard.
I'm just not sure how to correctly read in the instructions and turn it into binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10
#define SIZE 128
struct{
        const char *name;
        char *address;
}registers[] = {{ "zero", "00000"},
                { "at", "00001" },
                { "v0", "00010" },
                { "v1", "00011" },
                { "a0", "00100" },
                { "a1", "00101" },
                { "a2", "00110" },
                { "a3", "00111" },
                { "t0", "01000" },
                { "t1", "01001" },
                { "t2", "01010" },
                { "t3", "01011" },
                { "t4", "01100" },
                { "t5", "01101" },
                { "t6", "01110" },
                { "t7", "01111" },
                { "s0", "10000" },
                { "s1", "10001" },
                { "s2", "10010" },
                { "s3", "10011" },
                { "s4", "10100" },
                { "s5", "10101" },
                { "s6", "10110" },
                { "s7", "10111" },
                { "t8", "11000" },
                { "t9", "11001" },
                { NULL, 0 } };


struct{
        const char *name;
        char *function;
}rInst[] = {{ "add", "100000" },
                { "sub", "100001" },
                { "and", "100100" },
                { "or",  "100101" },
                { "sll", "000000" },
                { "slt", "101010" },
                { "srl", "000010" },
                { "jr",  "001000" },
                { NULL, 0 } };

struct {
        const char *name;
        char *function;
} iInst[] = {{ "lw",   "100011" },
                { "sw",   "101011" },
                { "andi", "001100" },
                { "ori",  "001101" },
                { "lui",  "001111" },
                { "beq",  "000100" },
                { "slti", "001010" },
                { "addi", "001000" },
                { NULL, 0 } };

struct inst{
        char opcode[MAX];
        char register1[MAX];
        char register2[MAX];
        char register3[MAX];
        int num;
        struct inst *next;
}*first, *current;

int main(){
         FILE *fp = fopen( "/home/js0939/CompOrg/MIPSLab5.txt", "r");
         char *result[10][4];
         char line[SIZE];
         char *value;
         if(fp == NULL){
                 printf("Error.");
                 return 1;
         }


    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    char* func;
    char* reg;

    // loop through each entry in file
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        //retrieves instruction
        value = strtok(line, " ");
        result[i][0] = strdup(value);
        for (i = 0; rInst[i].name != NULL; i++) {
                if (strcmp(value, rInst[i].name) == 0) {
                        func = rInst[i].function;
                        printf("%s ", func);
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; iInst[i].name != NULL; i++) {
                if (strcmp(value, iInst[i].name) == 0) {
                        func = iInst[i].function;
                        printf("%s ", func);
                }
        }

        //retrieves first register
        value = strtok(NULL, " ");
        result[i][1] = strdup(value);
        printf("%s ", value);
        for (i = 0; registers[i].name != NULL; i++){
                if(strcmp(value, registers[i].address) == 0){
                        reg = registers[i].address;
                        printf("%s ", reg);
                }
        }

        //retreives second register
        value = strtok(NULL, " ");
    result[i][2] = strdup(value);
        printf("%s ", value);
        for (i = 0; registers[i].name != NULL; i++){
                if(strcmp(value, registers[i].address) == 0){
                        reg = registers[i].address;
                        printf("%s ", reg);
                }
        }


        //retreives third register
        value = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        result[i][3] = strdup(value);
        printf("%s ", value);
        for (i = 0; registers[i].name != NULL; i++){
                if(strcmp(value, registers[i].address) == 0){
                        reg = registers[i].address;
                        printf("%s ", reg);
                }
        }


        //go to next line
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```